# Replace dependig on the value of the RegEx JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regEx of this form `/\\.br<[0-9]+>\\/g` and I want to replace it in the main text with the number of new lines indicated between the <> in the RegEx.

Ex. input

```
Hello \.br<3>\  World!
```

Output:

```
Hello


World!
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's not a code-writing service.

Comment: Look into the callback on `String.prototype.replace`.

Comment: not *number of spaces*, but the number of newlines, I suppose

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `/\\.br<[0-9]+>\\/g` is incorrect. `.` in the regex context means "any char except for line breaks". Hence, you'd need to escape the dot in your regex.

```
/\\\.br<[0-9]+>\\/g
/(\\\.br<([0-9]+)>\\)/g
```

Next, when taking a look at [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) as recommended by T.J. Crowder, the following solution comes to mind:

```js
    function replacer(match, p1, p2, offset, string) {
      let result = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < Number(p2); i++) {
        result += '\n';
      }
      return result;
    }
    var newString = String('Hello \\.br<3>\\ World!').replace(/(\\\.br<([0-9]+)>\\)/g, replacer);
    console.log(newString);
```

Note that the hardcoded string in the code contains 2 `\\`, since this is an escape character. When you receive the string from the user via a textfield of some kind, entering one `\` suffices.